# Cannot install keras on Windows OS

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip

Environment: Windows 11 x64, run CMD as Administrator, command

```
pip install keras
```

Console log

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))



C:\Windows\System32>pip install keras
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/keras/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/keras/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /keras/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /keras/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com/keras/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.ngc.nvidia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /keras/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.ngc.nvidia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

C:\Windows\System32>
```

[image]

How to install keras success in this context?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have anaconda/miniconda installed on your system but have not activated a conda environment in the command-line session.

You can first list available environments with `conda env list`. If you have never heard about them, and it just worked after you have installed anaconda/miniconda, you will probably see a single environment named "**base**". Activate this environment so that `conda` can "see" the packages in it: `conda activate base`. After the environment is activated, you should see its name - `(base)` - in the command prompt.

Now that you are in the appropriate environment, you can install the packages. On Windows I would recommend to use `conda` instead of `pip` for complex packages:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

On a side note, it's better, of cause, to create a separate environment for the project, rather than using "base", but this is a separate topic, not related to the issue. You can read more about the conda environments [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html).